# Failed to validate arguments being parsed to Expect Script

Tags: expect

I am writing an Expect script for first time, and I would like to have a checker to validate user arguments. But I am getting errors as following, please do let me know if you know what has went wrong. Thanks

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

if {$argc != 1}
{
        puts 'Insert IP address of tftp server'
        exit 1
}
```

This is the erro

```
jeff@mymachine:/home/jeff~$ ./test.sh
wrong # args: no script following "$argc != 1" argument
    while executing
"if {$argc != 1}"
    (file "./test.sh" line 3)
```

Comment: looks like u r more familiar with shell scripts. take a look at [*sexpect*](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) with which you can write *Expect* scripts with shell code only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expect is based on Tcl.  As your code is written, the Tcl parser does not know that the `if` statement is supposed to continue on the next line.  You can fix this by writing either

```
if {$argc != 1} \
{
    puts 'Insert IP address of tftp server'
    exit 1
}
```

or

```
if {$argc != 1} {
    puts 'Insert IP address of tftp server'
    exit 1
}
```

Comment: Actually a second issue is that single quotes have no significance to Tcl so the `puts` command should probably be `puts {Insert IP address of tftp server}`

Comment: I used `send_user` instead of `puts` and everything is fine.